# Is there anyway to generate doc strings for Python code using Github Copilot (VS Code)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

Is there anyway to generate doc string using Github Copilot

I have code and I want to generate doc string for it.

```
def make_chat_content(self,chat_uuid,text,db_session):
    import uuid

    all_content = ChatContent.query.filter_by(chat_uuid=chat_uuid).all()
    chat_json = dump(all_content)
    chat_json.append({"role":"user","content":text})
    response, total_words_generated = self.chat.get_response(chat_json)
```

for example doc string that describes function

```
"""
Add the user's text to the chat content and generate a response.

This function takes the chat UUID, user's text, and a database session as input.
It appends the user's content to the existing chat content, generates a response
using a chat model, and returns the response along with the total words generated.

Args:
    chat_uuid (str): The UUID of the chat session.
    text (str): The text content provided by the user.
    db_session: The database session for querying chat content.

Returns:
    tuple: A tuple containing the response generated by the chat model and
           the total number of words generated in the response.
"""
```

Comment: if you give the function a proper name you don't need doc strings

Comment: But can we do it using Github Copilot in VS Code?

Comment: **IMHO:** At this point in time? I would say: No. All these LLMs predict what is most likely the next word. What you want is an analysis of your code, and from that a describing text. This **may** work for basic commands like **print** but what about self defined functions, what about not that common function, for example: [**shelves**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#module-shelve)? How should the LLM possibly know what you did there and write a decent description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Looks like it can be done:

[image]

*Only test the sample code in the post.*

Comment: Which keys to press to show this option while selecting the code?

Comment: https://imgur.com/MbFkmwp.png

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, those are useful strategies for using Copilot to streamline your coding process:

1. When working on a class or multiple functions that are interdependent:

   - Start by writing one or two functions.
   - After completing your initial functions, place your cursor at the `:` character after the function definition, press enter, and begin typing `"""`. Copilot will automatically generate a docstring for you.
   - Now, when you type `def function_name():`, Copilot will auto-generate both the function's body and its accompanying docstring.
2. For simpler cases or standalone functions, you can directly use the second step from the previous instructions, which involves just generating a docstring for a function by typing `"""` after the function definition.